# 18.04, gnome tweaks: change color of mouse pointer location

Tags: gnome, themes, gnome-tweak-tool

In gnome tweak tool you can select "Position of Pointer" to get a highlighted mouse pointer, if you press `crtl`. Currently, it only works with xorg (wayland support will be added in Gnome 3.34).

However, the color of the highlighting is black making it rather difficult to be seen on dark backgrounds. Is there any way to change it's color?

EDIT:

It seems that the color is black because of the communitheme (light **and** dark). In Ambiance it's orange. The question remains. How to change this certain aspect of a theme?

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.2.

Comment: is wayland involved in question or we need to concentrate answer for xorg only?

Comment: xorg only since it's not working at all on wayland right now. Just added it for wayland users who may wonder why this feature doesn't work on their machine.

Comment: 0k thats nice.. let me go through for xorg..

Comment: I tried to reproduce it on 18.04.2 but its orange in color..

Comment: I use the dark communitheme. I changed to different themes via gnome tweak but it didn't change the color, so I thought thats not the reason. But since the communitheme isn't native in 18.04, I need to open my session "with communitheme" when I log in. So I guess thats the problem then. The question where the color can be changed remains though.

Comment: @PRATAP Okey, I tried to log in with the default (without communitheme) and it didn't change the color. Before the dark communitheme was available, I downloaded "Yaru-Dark" (https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1252100/). Has this changed the color?